# Query is not returning expected results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table where I keep customers. And another where I keep sales.

When I save some I keep selling the customer id, and when I show in a list,
I show the customer with the id

The problem is, when looking for a sale not leave me alone those of the logged client shows me all the records

```
$query = "SELECT  * 
  FROM ventas 
  WHERE idusuario = $_SESSION[k_username] 
  union 
  SELECT  * 
  FROM reparaciones 
  WHERE marca LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' 
  OR modelo LIKE '%" . $name ."%'" ;
```

And  this

```
$query="SELECT  * 
  FROM ventas 
  WHERE idusuario = $_SESSION[k_username] 
     marca LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' 
  OR modelo LIKE '%" . $name ."%'";
```

But none of them works

Comment: You'll need `$_SESSION[k_username]` in quotes, for example `idusuario = '$_SESSION[k_username]' ` What is the table structure?

Comment: @chris85 Strictly, yes, but PHP allows one to get away with this. Unfortunately.

Comment: I mean as SQL string. I should edit I guess..

Comment: `marca` is not valid sql, and makes that query entirely invalid. maybe you mean `AND marca`?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO.

I would highly recommend you do some research on [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). I will address your question as is without accounting for the security vulnerabilities with the way you currently have it setup.

Your query strings are not valid, try this:

```
$query = "SELECT  * 
    FROM ventas 
    WHERE idusuario = '". $_SESSION['k_username'] ."' 
    UNION 
    SELECT  * 
    FROM reparaciones 
    WHERE marca LIKE '%". $name ."%'
        OR modelo LIKE '%". $name ."%'
    ";
```

and

```
$query = "SELECT  * 
    FROM ventas 
    WHERE idusuario = '". $_SESSION['k_username'] ."' 
        OR marca LIKE '%". $name ."%' 
        OR modelo LIKE '%". $name ."%'
    ";
```

Also, in your first query you are using a union, please make sure both parts of that query return the same number of columns.

**UPDATE**

Examples of SQL Injection can be found all over the internet (including on the php.net manual page I linked to above). From the example you gave in the OP, it is not clear if you are sanitizing your data, namely: $_SESSION['k_username'] and $name and as you are including these directly in your query string, these may be injection points.

For example, if $name happens to be user input (say from a search form) and the user supplies:

```
x'; DELETE FROM usuario WHERE 1=1; --
```

Now when that is used in your second query, your query string becomes (just using 123 for the user id as an example):

```
SELECT  * FROM ventas WHERE idusuario = 123 OR marca LIKE '%x'; DELETE FROM usuario WHERE 1=1; --%' OR modelo LIKE '%". $name ."%'
```

Now when that query runs your user table becomes empty.

This, of course, is only one example. Perhaps your user table isn't called 'usuario'... The fact still remains that you have a vulnerability and it leaves an opening for someone to infiltrate your system. Perhaps they will only skim some data (usernames, passwords, contact information, etc), perhaps they will inject their own data, perhaps they will destroy your entire database, who knows. Do you really want to take that risk?

So here is an example of how you could use a prepared statement to help mitigate that risk:

```
$sql = "SELECT  * 
    FROM ventas 
    WHERE idusuario = :userid 
        OR marca LIKE ':name'
        OR modelo LIKE ':name'
    ";
$params = array(
    'userid' => $_SESSION['k_username'],
    'name' => '%'. $name .'%'
);

$db = new PDO(...); // replace ... with your connection info
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($params);
$results = $query->fetchAll();
```

This is just an example, there are other ways (some examples listed in the links above).

Comment: i think this is the best answer because it suggest the use of prepared statements, you should try them

Comment: hii :)
there are somehow better not to admit SQL injection, 
sam demo of your part, please

Comment: @e-jay-loco i updated my answer with some examples.